Does the politics SE site (as it pertains to American politics) only welcome questions suburban right wing whites would find palatable?
I find my usually left-wing questions get smothered with decorum issues (that I find preternaturally infantile and annoying) or closed with specious reasons as to why they are not appropriate for the site.
For example, It is beyond belief that this
Are Blue State companies moving to Texas primarily due to the political leanings of their top executives?
question was closed as "not appropriate".
It looks like site participants get offended by left wing viewpoints and would rather erase those viewpoints from the site instead of factually and logically debating them.

** This is intended to be helpful to you **  I assume that you have ideas and thoughts that have questions and thoughts worth interaction on this site. A suggestion for when you write comments - write as you would talk to someone face to face. Take this advice with with a grain of salt. I personally don't care what someone's point of view is. Just don't treat me like I am an idiot or a fool. I try to never treat someone without respect. I am afraid that my interactions with you just don't seem that way. As I said before, I am trying to be helpful. If you don't find this helpful, please ignore.

suburban right wing whites .  Please leave out racial/ethnic characteristics unless they are directly relevant to a question.  I don't feel offended/hurt/marginalized or any such thing by your choice of words.  I don't care one whit if you like or dislike white people.  I don't care if you're white yourself.  I do know that when users bring in "Black/Muslim/..." in a rather negative manner irrelevant to the question, this is not well received.  If this was a question accusing some whites of racism, of course ethnicity would be relevant.  I might even agree.  Irrelevant here, and flagged.

You may be getting some downvotes due to the themes of your questions, and due to the right-wing bias here—men lean Republican, IT leans male, SE leans towards IT, so it would not be much of a surprise—but you are also getting downvotes due to the quality and presentation of your questions. One of your questions got upvoted: asking whether Southernness modulates urban versus rural divides in US politics. That was a good question, and guess what? It got upvoted.

To consider the two downvoted questions, I actually agree with the basic underlying ideas. Yes, some businesses move to Texas because they feel dissatisfied with more liberal states, and yes, Republican emphasis on unlimited gun rights has put even Republican politicians in danger. Clearly, I didn't downvote them because I am a suburban Republican who disagrees with their underlying ideas.

Rather, one is borderline off-topic: some conservative business owners might take politics into account when moving their businesses, but a question would need a bit more than to be on-topic. Making it more broad-scale, about net flow of businesses overall from liberal to conservative states, might have worked. The other: while it's an idea that I kind of agree with, it's very pushy ("Republican policies on guns are so bad even they get hurt, the clowns.") and opinion-based and hyperbolic (what is "impossible" and how would we determine it?)

Framed a different way (for instance, "How much has Republican opposition to gun control affected the safety of politicians?"), it would have even received my upvote.

To give a clear example of how your approach to questions matters as much as the right-wing bias here. On the English site, where you are temporarily suspended, you asked a push question challenging the use of "murder" to refer to Kristi Noem killing a dog, including harshly criticizing answers that said that "murder" was an appropriate term. Insofar as Noem is a right-wing politician, and animal welfare (particularly the notion of animals having legal rights and personhood) is much bigger priority on the left, saying that she murdered a dog is pretty clearly a left-wing coded position.

Yet somehow, your question challenging this was heavily downvoted on the English site. Is this because there is a left-wing bloc there? Or just a general dislike of push questions?

There isn't ANY way I can reply without getting banned to kingdom come. @Obie2.0

If you can't think of a way to respond that is not so disrespectful as to get banned, that sounds like something to work on.

This is about the nicest advice you are going to get, I'm afraid. It's coming from someone who agrees that there is right-wing bias on this site, and does not think that the general ideas underlying the questions that you have asked on the politics Stack Exchange are incorrect, but is giving you some tips on how to frame them in ways that are neither pushy nor off-topic. Most people are not going to give you that much. If you want to see that as "ugly viciousness"—while framing objections to your own debatably ugly statements (e.g. "infantile")—as a mere pretense of decorum, it's up to you.

The question was closed as "not on topic" which just means it's not on topic here.  That's not a judgement of whether or not it's a good question, whether or not it's expressing opinions people (dis)agree with, whether or not it's appropriate, or whether or not it's even answerable.  It's literally just what the close reason says:

This question does not appear to be about governments, policies and political processes within the scope defined in the help center.
...
Questions asking for the internal motivations of people ... are off-topic, because answers would be based on speculation and their correctness could not be verified with sources available to the public.

If you're asking us why companies (via their board or CEO) have decided to relocate, there's no way to answer that without being in their head.  If you're asking us whether or not they're doing better after the move, that's not a question about politics.  Either way, it's not something we can answer.
If you were asking a question about whether companies in blue/red states were more likely to express liberal/conservative political stances, that would be on topic, because it's about companies publicly weighing in on politics.  If you were asking whether a specific policy decision led to a significant change in the business landscape in a state, that would also be on topic.
So it has nothing to do with what anyone considers "palatable".
